# Change color inactive track on the left/right of a RangeSlider

Tags: android, android-slider

I have a RangeSlider, with two custom thumbs. I have to use 3 different colors: one for the inactive track on the left of the first thumb, one for the active track and one for the inactive track on the right of the second thumb.

There is any way to archive that?

```
    <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
    android:id="@+id/rangeslider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:valueFrom="100"
    android:valueTo="3000"
    app:haloRadius="1dp"
    app:labelBehavior="gone"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tickVisible="false"
    app:values="@array/initial_slider_values" />
```